# Livewire live search does not work on FreeBSD

Tags: c#, freebsd, laravel-livewire, livesearch

I have an application developed in Laravel on a Vagrant box and deployed to a FreeBSD server. I have recently updated the application to use the Livewire datatables live search function.

Everything works as expected on the Vagrant box, but the live search does not work on the FreeBSD server. I have tried different versions of FreeBSD and Linux, and MySQL/MariaDB, and a number of demo live search applications, but the search function fails consistently on FreeBSD and works consistently on Linux.

Any ideas on how to activate this function on FreeBSD would be greatly appreciated.

Using Nginx 1.18.0/1.20.2, PHP 7.4, MySQL 5.7/8.0

**Works on:**

Vagrant box:
Linux 5.4.0-88-generic #99-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 23 17:29:00 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Debian:
Linux 5.10.0-11-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.92-1 (2022-01-18) x86_64 GNU/Linux

**Fails on:**

FreeBSD:
FreeBSD 12.2-RELEASE-p7 FreeBSD 12.2-RELEASE-p7 GENERIC  amd64
FreeBSD 13.0-RELEASE #0 releng/13.0-n244733-ea31abc261f

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Peter at freebsd@boosten.org.
The answer was in the nginx log (can't believe I didn't find it):
/usr/local/www/sgbdb/public/livewire/livewire.js"
failed (2: No such file or directory)

On linux it works with the js file at:
./vendor/livewire/livewire/dist/livewire.js

### Not sure if I missed something in the setup but putting a copy of the js in
public/livewire/livewire.js
solved the problem.

Rob